# why delete button is inactive in outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

One of my users say that in outlook 2010 the Delete option for removing messages is gray and become inactive.
whats caused this problem and whats its solution?

Comment: Please try to identify the cause and post it in detail such as email type, is it only for that user... etc to assist you better..

Comment: I'm betting the user has selected a folder such as the mail folder, which can't be deleted. So obviously the delete button greys out in this case...

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if the user is right? First of all you need to check if its an "user error".
Is it possible to remove messages with the del key?

Comment: I assume DEL key does the same function as the application does. Therefore, it may not work. Let's see what he replies back :)

Comment: For me it has the same function, it moves the e-mail the the trash folder.

Comment: Azker Mohamed is right. Del key is not working. and this problem is for a specific user. He can't delete his messages...